# How to use map function inside an isolated function in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

Following is my code. VS code plugin complains that the function used inside the map is not an isolated function. What is the problem with it.

```
class Node {
    (int|string)[] path;

    isolated function init((int|string)[] path) {
        self.path = path;
    }

    isolated function getPath() returns string[] {
        return self.path.clone().'map(n => n is int ? "@" : n);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here seems to be due to a [bug](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/39803) in inferring if the (infer) anonymous function is an `isolated` function when there's type narrowing of a parameter.

As a workaround, you would have to explicitly specify that the function is an `isolated` function.

```
class Node {
    (int|string)[] path;

    isolated function init((int|string)[] path) {
        self.path = path;
    }

    isolated function getPath() returns string[] {
        return self.path.map(
            isolated function (int|string n) returns string => n is int ? "@" : n);
    }
}
```